# Nuxt3 prerender all routes

Tags: nuxtjs3

Nuxt will prerender and generate payload for almost all routes.

However for dynamic pages I believe you need to specify inside **nuxt.config**

```
nitro: {
    prerender: {
        crawlLinks: false,
        routes: [
            // all my routes goes here
        ]
    }
 }
```

My problem is where to make the fetch for all my routes and how to import it to **nuxt.config** the result.

Comment: Why do you disable the crawl? You can do it pretty much anywhere and send the array down to `routes` I guess. There is nothing in the docs on that subject?

Comment: Nuxt anyway generates payload for all pages inside page directory. The rest of pages are the dynamic pages that he does not see even with crowl set to true.

Comment: I have not found anything in the documentation, I wanted to create some js file where I will do my fetching logic, then to import the result in nuxt.config.

Comment: This is for Nuxt2 but may still be relevant: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/configuration-glossary/configuration-generate#function-with-a-callback

Comment: I think this is the way for Nuxt3 https://github.com/nuxt/framework/issues/4919

Comment: I use Sanity as headless CMS for my data fetching. My issue now is to bring the Sanity client inside nuxt.config.

Comment: You can probably fetch it with a token inside of the `nuxt.config.js` file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments above by mart cube, this is what works in Nuxt 3.8.2 :
(my nuxt config is also testing multilingual, that's why I create 2 arrays. Essentially you can do anything you want inside the getRoutes function, as long as you return an array of routes)

Here's the whole config file:

```
import axios from "axios";

const getRoutes = async () => {

    const endpoint = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts'
    const response = await axios.get(endpoint)
    let articles = response.data.slice(0, 20);

    let slugsFR = articles.map((each:any) => { return '/presse/' + each.id })
    let slugsEN = articles.map((each:any) => { return '/en/articles/' + each.id })
    const all = [...slugsFR, ...slugsEN];
    return all
}


export default defineNuxtConfig({
  devtools: { enabled: true 
  },

  modules: [
    '@nuxtjs/tailwindcss',
    ['@nuxtjs/i18n', { locales: ['fr', 'en'], defaultLocale: 'fr', } ],
  ],


  hooks: {
    async 'nitro:config'(nitroConfig) {
        if (nitroConfig.dev) { return }
        let slugs = await getRoutes();
        //@ts-ignore
        nitroConfig.prerender.routes.push(...slugs)
        return
    }
  },

})
```

Comment: In this article the problem is explained in deeper details.
https://roe.dev/blog/shared-data-nuxt-generate